# tokenize array consisting of strings

Tags: python, for-loop, nltk, tokenize

I have an array called allchats consisting of long strings. some of the places in the index look like the following:

```
allchats[5,0] = "Hi, have you ever seen something like that? no?"
allchats[106,0] = "some word blabla some more words yes"
allchats[410,0] = "I don't know how we will ever get through this..."
```

I wish to tokenize each string in the array. Furthermore I wish to use a regex tool to eliminate questionsmarks, commas etc.

I have tried the following:

```
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import RegexTokenizer

tknzr = RegexTokenizer('\w+')
allchats1 = [[tknzr.tokenize(chat) for chat in str] for str in allchats]
```

I wish to end up with:

```
allchats[5,0] = ['Hi', 'have', 'you', 'ever', 'seen', 'something', 'like', 'that', 'no']
allchats[106,0] = '[some', 'word', 'blabla', 'some', 'more', 'words', 'yes']
allchats[410,0] = ['I', 'dont', 'know', 'how', 'we', 'will', 'ever', 'get', 'through', 'this']
```

I am quite sure that I am doing something wrong with the strings (str) in the for loop, but cannot figure out what I need to correct in order to succeed.

Thank you in advance for you help!

Comment: `tknzr.tokenize(chat) for chat in str` will take every character of you sentence separately, is that what you want ?

Comment: @UlysseBN no, I wish to separate the words, so more like tknzr.tokenize(chat) for chat in word, if that makes sense.

Comment: ok I'll add this to my answer

Comment: Also why the indices of your list are tuple and not integers ?

Comment: I should have written print(allchats.ix[1,]) instead. This gives me the first row.
If I type print(type(allchats.ix[1,]) I get class = 'str'.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo error on your list comprehension, it doesn't take nested lists, but chained lists:

```
allchats1 = [tknzr.tokenize(chat) for str in allchats for chat in str]
```

If you want to iterate over words instead of just characters, you are looking for [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method. So [here is a fully working exmple](https://repl.it/KU0Q):

```
allchats = ["Hi, have you ever seen something like that? no?", "some word blabla some more words yes", "I don't know how we will ever get through this..."]

def tokenize(word):
    # use real logic here
    return word + 'tokenized'

tokenized = [tokenize(word) for sentence in allchats for word in sentence.split()]

print(tokenized)
```

If you're not sure you have only strings in your list and want to go over only strings, you can check this with `isinstance` method ([example here](https://repl.it/KU0Q/1)):

```
tokenized = [tokenize(word) for sentence in allchats if isinstance(sentence, str) for word in sentence.split()]
```

Comment: Hi, when applying this I end up with a TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable. Any idea why?

Comment: I'd like to see you `allchats` list to answer you

Comment: With the edited code, I get an error of similar type: AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'split'.
Info about allchats is: it is of 497x1 dimensions, each row is of type = str, and the dataframe itself is pandas.core.series.Series. Is this of any help?

Comment: Well this means you have float in `allchats`, but you can filter them out, see my edited answer

Comment: Can I change this from float to strings so I can use the for loop that you proposed at first?

Comment: I believe this has to be done for the whole array, so something like, str(chat) for chat in allchats, is that correct? Or is there a smarter way?

Comment: You're right, you can do it while iterating for tokenization